# How can I place two items next to each other and make both of them wrap only when necessary?

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a way to place two elements next to each other. One element contains a link and the other element two buttons. If it is not possible to fit both elements without a line break, both should wrap at the same time:

big screen:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
https://this-is-a-link.com/with-a-slug                           c  x |
https://this-is-a-link.com/with-a-long-long-long-long-long-slug  c  x |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

small screen:

```
-------------------------------------
https://this-is-a-link.com/with-  c |
a-slug                            x |
https://this-is-a-link.com/with-  c |
a-long-long-long-long-long-slug   x |
-------------------------------------
```

What I want to avoid is a scenerio where one element would wrap, but the other would not:

```
-------------------------------------
https://this-is-a-link.com/with-  c x |
a-slug                                |
https://this-is-a-link.com/with-  c x |
a-long-long-long-long-long-slug       |
-------------------------------------
```

I want to avoid this also:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
https://this-is-a-link.com/with-a-slug                           c |
                                                                 x |
https://this-is-a-link.com/with-a-long-long-long-long-long-slug  c |
                                                                 x |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The markup currently looks like this, but can be changed if needed

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <span class="link">https://this-is-a-link.com/with-a-slug</span>
    <span class="buttons">
      <button>c</button>
      <button>x</button>
    </span>
  </li>
   <li>
    <span class="link">https://this-is-a-link.com/with-a-long-long-long-long-long-slug</span>
    <span class="buttons">
      <button>c</button>
      <button>x</button>
    </span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

And [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kun8zd5w/) is a basic setup in a fiddle.

```css
ol {
  background: lightgrey;
  max-width: 600px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <span class="link">https://this-is-a-link.com/with-a-slug</span>
    <span class="buttons">
      <button>c</button>
      <button>x</button>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="link">https://this-is-a-link.com/with-a-long-long-long-long-long-slug</span>
    <span class="buttons">
      <button>c</button>
      <button>x</button>
    </span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

I tried various things I could think of, like making each `li` element `flex` or trying to put the whole list into a `grid` (trying various `minmax()` combinations), but I was never able to achieve the effect I would like to see as described above. I have always been running into situations where elements would rather wrap instead of taking the whole space or one element would wrap and the other would refuse to.

Comment: The closest I was able to get is to use a grid and specify `max-content` for all elements. However, this would push elements out of the visible area, when the screen gets too small, which I was not able to solve so far. Something like https://jsfiddle.net/j3z01epk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/6hwaL0zy/

```
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li .buttons {
  text-align: right;
}
```

I think it fits your requirements but there's a intermedium case that you did not specify (when the second row wraps and the first doesn't)

Comment: @ThierryLemaitre the elements that should wrap are not using `display: flex`, check the jsfiddle link, `.links` and `.buttons` both wrap  when needed

Comment: intermediate states are inevitably a compromise here, so I just left them out. Thanks for your help. Now I just need to figure out why I tried to make such a simple thing so complicated :D

Answer (score 1):

```css
ol {
  background: lightgrey;
  max-width: 600px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.parent{
  display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="parent">
    <span class="link">https://this-is-a-link.com/with-a-slug</span>
    <span class="buttons">
      <button>c</button>
      <button>x</button>
    </span>
  </li>
   <li  class="parent">
    <span class="link">https://this-is-a-link.com/with-a-long-long-long-long-long-slug</span>
    <span class="buttons">
      <button>c</button>
      <button>x</button>
    </span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: add parent class as above mentioned

Comment: .parent{
  display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

by default, flex-direction is a row, if the screen size shrinks button will be moved to the next line by using flex-wrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using bootstrap by making `<div class="row">` and put two columns under it like 1 for your link and other for your two buttons.

for e.g:

```
    <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">
        your link code
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        your buttons code
         </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: adding bootstrap to compensate for my lack of knowledge about the finer details of css seems just a little bit of overkill

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your CSS class

```
.buttons{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: just using `display: flex` will put the buttons into a new row, which is not what I am looking for.